# What is the female equivalent of the morning erection that some men experience?

Tags: human-biology, endocrinology, sex

[There was question](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/19879/what-causes-morning-wood) about what causes "morning wood." It was answered that the erection in the morning is caused by decline of norepinephrine during REM sleep. Which in part allows to prevent uncontrolled urination.

My question is: How does the decline in norepinephrine affect women? They obviously don't get erection.

Comment: `This question is protected to prevent "thanks!", "me too!"...` - that's quite funny protection :)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Women have erections too! These erections are called [clitoral erection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clitoral_erection). Clitoral erections are usually accompanied with [vaginal lubrification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vaginal_lubrication).

Just like men (see [here](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/19879/what-causes-morning-wood)), the absence of norepinephrine during the [REM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rapid_eye_movement_sleep) phase of the sleep causes erections. In women, this phenomenon is called [Nocturnal clitoral tumescence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nocturnal_clitoral_tumescence) while it is called [Nocturnal penile tumescence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nocturnal_penile_tumescence) in men. In women, not only the clitoris get engorged with blood but the vagina too.

Comment: You sure? Because I have only had 1 typical sign of a female orgasm and only once. And I haven't been sexually active in my life. What I felt was a vaginal contraction. For a few seconds it felt like I could control menstrual flow. I myself have never had a clitoral erection though I have had noticeable vaginal discharge increase related to my menstrual cycle.

Comment: @Caters It is not a sign of orgasm just like discharge isn't. Both can be signs of arousal. Clitoral (and vaginal) erection possibly results in outer (closer to the entrance) vaginal tightening and as far as I am aware (I don't have a vagina, so I can only rely to womens' reports) if one touches clitoris when there is no erection it is not as pleasant (or even unpleasant) feeling than when there is an erection. But it might be the case that not every woman has these.